# Hibernate Query with Same Parameter Value with thread sleep but getting same result although DB update row value

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am facing a problem with Hibernate Query. When I query with parameter with thread sleep, if first time if get null it always null.

@Repository Class Query

```java
    @Repository
    public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer,Long> {
        @Query("select re FROM Customer re WHERE re.name like:name and re.email like:email")
        Customer  getCustomer(@Param("name") String name , @Param("email") String email );
      }
```

Service

```java
    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;


    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(threadSleepTime);
             } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
             }
    
             Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
             session.clear();
    
       
         Customer  customer = customerRepository.getByCustomer("sujon", "sujon@gmail.com");
       }
```

The Customer Object getting every time null although second or third(when i=3,4) it create row by this name and email by another application.

As I mentioned I clear session but result same.

Seeking Help.

Comment: How and when do you create the row? When you are already in the for loop or before?

Comment: You are clearing the entity manager to avoid its cache, but it's still running in the same SQL transaction, so it likely can't see data inserted/updated after it's been started.